# Traceback (most recent call last):NameError: name 'path' is not defined

Tags: python

I am new to this subject in Python. I Transmitted Data While Doing Autopilot And Finally Got An Error Like This:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\eminn\Desktop\Autopilot_V2\LoadData_V2.py", line 46, in <module>
    return_data()
  File "c:\Users\eminn\Desktop\Autopilot_V2\LoadData_V2.py", line 29, in return_data
    full_path = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER, path)
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

A Small Screenshot from the console:
[image]

complete code:

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import islice

LIMIT = None

DATA_FOLDER = 'driving_dataset'
TRAIN_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER, 'data.txt')

def preprocess(img):
    resized = cv2.resize((cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV))[:, :, 1], (100, 100))
    return resized

def return_data():

    X = []
    y = []
    features = []

    with open(TRAIN_FILE) as fp:
        for line in islice(fp, LIMIT):
            for line in islice(fp, LIMIT):     print(f"Read Line: {line}") #==> new line of code     path, angle = line.strip().split()
            #path, angle = line.strip().split()
            full_path = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER, path)
            X.append(full_path)
            # using angles from -pi to pi to avoid rescaling the atan in the network
            y.append(float(angle) * scipy.pi / 180)

    for i in range(len(X)):
        img = plt.imread(X[i])
        features.append(preprocess(img))

    features = np.array(features).astype('float32')
    labels = np.array(y).astype('float32')

    with open("features", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(features, f, protocol=4)
    with open("labels", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(labels, f, protocol=4)

return_data()
```

Previously, it was giving an error from the tensorflow module. After I downloaded tensorflow, I am doing it again, but I am getting an error in Guinea.
Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `path` variable commented out, you need to define it or uncomment it